# Error trying to parse file: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages\User\Default\(Windows).sublime-keymap:2:28

Tags: parsing

Ok guys, this is what I get when I try to run Sublime Text 3. Mind you, the program still works but the alert d-box is annoying. How can I get rid of it? Thanks!

[image: SublimeText3]

Comment: Did it ever run or was it fresh, first-time Installation on your box? Did you edit anything in config files? If yes, please include the modified config parts.

Comment: First time I ever got that message. I was trying to alter some files in order to be able to use certain keyboard shortcuts but wasn't successful so I left everything as it was. Now all of a sudden I get a parsing error alert box.

Answer (score 0):

do you get that problem when you launch SublimeText?..it seems a error when trying to parse a SublimeText file or maybe some of your files. I understood that you have to separate your word by commas..but i dont know exactly..

Comment: Yeah. It's the first thing that pops up in my screen after I double click the Sublime icon. After clicking OK the alert box disappears and Sublime starts running.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you saved (accidently) some of these config files and messed up the syntax. check for modification date of the files you touched. Probably is the file `Packages\User\Default\(Windows).sublime-keymap`, line 2, column 28.

If you can't work out the hick-up, edit your post and include the line(s) of that file-